# FancyBox PHP form submit issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

Okay, so I've been having a problem for the past four days, and a couple hours ago, I think I may have solved part of it (fancybox example #5, on their site, seems to be something that I want), however, I cannot get any part of it to work.

```
    <?  if($_GET['page'] != "startTime"){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#startTime").fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'onClosed'      : function() {
            $("#login_error").hide();}
            })
        });
        $("#startTimeForm").bind("submit", function() {
        if ($("#year").val().length < 4) {
            $("#login_error").show();
            $.fancybox.resize();
            return false;
        }
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            cache   : false,
            url     : "downTime.php?page=ajax",
            data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
            success : function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
        });
    </script>
<? } ?>
<? if($_GET['page'] == "ajax"){
var_dump($_POST); } ?>
<? if($_GET['page'] == "startTime"){?>
<div style="width:250px" class="new">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="new">
   <tr>
   <form id="startTimeForm" method=post>
    <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
   <tr>
    <td>Enter Year</td>
    <td><input class="czas" id="sec" name="year" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="00" /></td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><br /><input class="czas" type="submit" name="newTime" value="Set Start Time" /></td></tr>
   </form>
```

I also had used a javascript function, below, and I'd eventually like that to work in the code above, but I cannot get the above to work properly. It just does nothing. Firebug also reports no errors.

```
<script>
    function closeFB() {
    <? $unix = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $_POST['year']); ?>
    $("#startTimeDiv").html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $("#message").html("<p>Contact Form Submitted!</p>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.<br><? echo $unix; ?></p>");
    $.fancybox.close(); 
    }
    </script>
```

So, any help would be appreciated. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you have no errors at all are you sure that your PHP if statement is correct and the code is inserted in the resulting document?

Comment: Also the path on your fancybox script include looks wrong. I think that would evaluate to just `/` but if you're going for `./` I doubt it's working right

Comment: Firebug reports no errors, but the fancybox code does not work. And, the /./ surprisingly does work when the fancybox call code was "$(document).ready(function() { $("#startTime").fancybox({'padding' : 0})});" and I has onClick="closeFB();" in the submit line. What I'm trying to get is the user to click a button, open FB, input data, hit the submit button, have FB close and update the div, at the same time running the mktime PHP function. But, I've read on here that in order for a submit button to work with FB, one needs the type of code of example #5 on FB website, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demonstration [here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loginFormV2_02jul12.html) worked to solve the problem. It created another problem, but that is for another question. I believe that was your demo, JFK, so thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "downTime.php?page=ajax",
        data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success : function(data) {
```

**Instead of:**

```
            $.fancybox(data);
```

**Try**

```
            $("#fancyboxdiv").fancybox(data);

        }
    });
```

Where fancyboxdiv is the name of your element that hosts the fancybox.

You will change the other functions to

```
$("#fancyboxdiv").fancybox().close()
```

etc..
Most JQuery UI components require a element to work off of as its parent and it will usually modify that element adding/removing elements to it and changing CSS to give appearance that is needed

Comment: That is not the way fancybox works. Check the documentation at http://fancybox.net/api specifically the part of "public methods".