# Fancybox issues, should not be showing certain things, yet is

Tags: fancybox

I have tried to re-do some stuff, trying to get working code and then to modify it with what I need it to be once I get something working. Problem is, I've tried to copy Fancybox's #5 example, and titleshow is set to false, yet the title shows, as well as #login_error is supposed to be hidden, yet it shows from the start.

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tip5").fancybox();
});

$("#tip5").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'onClosed'      : function() {
        $("#login_error").hide();
    }
});

$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
        $("#login_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "/data/login.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a id="tip5" title="Login" href="#login_form">Login</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
        <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_name">Login: </label>
            <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_pass">Password: </label>

            <input type="password" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox PHP form submit issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582659/fancybox-php-form-submit-issue)

Comment: try editing your previous question and provide feedback in the comments area instead of opening a new question with exactly the same code.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I was going to ask for one part of it here, separate from the other question, but I guess that didn't come off right. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demonstration [here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loginFormV2_02jul12.html) worked to solve the problem. It created another problem, but that is for another question. I believe that was your demo, JFK, so thank you.